# Encoding of output artifacts from 'openssl req' command?

Tags: encoding, openssl, command

My question is simply: What is the encoding of the .pem and .csr file created by openssl using this command:

```
openssl req -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout key.pem -out some.csr \
    -subj "/C=XY/ST=UVW/L=SOMETOWN/O=STH/OU=STHELSE/CN=my.cert.test"
```

I do past some information from which i do not know if they are of importance for the answer of this question:

I am working on a xterm under x11. I have a up to date linux distribution (opensuse leap 42.2) and use openssl in my shell to create a csr file. I have a setting in my env `XTERM_LOCALE=de_DE.UTF-8`.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: To answer your question, `key.pem` and `some.csr` are both PEM encoded. But why did you need to ask the question here? A simple `cat key.pem` or `cat some.csr` would have answered your question.

Comment: You might also want to look at [How do you sign Certificate Signing Request with your Certification Authority](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21340898/608639) and [How to create a self-signed certificate with openssl?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10175812/608639)

Comment: @offtopic: the certificate is the data my software operates on. Is the question still off topic?

Comment: When i cat the file how do i know the encoding?

Answer (score 0):

You can set encoding by passing `-outform DER` or `-outform PEM` where der is binary file and pem is in base64.

Comment: but I have picked csr and pem... I mean encoding like latin1, utf-8, ascii and the like...